# Getting all radio buttons in a form using Prototype or plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a simple form which includes lots of radio buttons. Some of them are selected, some of the are not. Is there a way to get them all and set them to not checked. I guess setting to not checked can be done like this:

```
button.checked = false;
```

Question is, how do I get all the buttons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(c){
    $(c).checked = false;
});
```

Comment: The double `$$` should give it away as prototype

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked (I've never seen or used Prototype, I was just curious).

Comment: You don't need `$()` after `$$()` - all elements in result are already extended.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is tagged both [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs). If you want more syntactic sugar from PrototypeJS, then answer may look like

```
$$('input[type="radio"]:checked').invoke('setValue', false);
```

translation from `Prototype` to english sounds like `invoke setValue(false) operation on all checked radio buttons`.

To search in one form you can use somewhat similar construction

```
$('yourFormId').select('input[type="radio"]:checked').invoke('setValue', false);
```

If you want plain old IE6-compatible JavaScript, then answer will be

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; ++i) {
  if (inputs[i].type === "radio") {
    inputs[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="radio"]' );
```

This will return a NodeList with all `<input>` elements of type radio. You can then traverse the list an change the `checked` attribute for all.

Comment: In which browsers is this available? I've never seen this before!

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is supported by almost all modern browsers. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector).

Comment: Was just searching for that!

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == "radio") {
        inputs[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

Note that getElementsByTagName is not support in some older IEs...

Comment: `document.forms.formName.getElementByTagName("input");` might narrow it down a bit

Comment: Thanks! But I believe the OP wanted to uncheck all the radio buttons on the page, so it may not be exactly what he wants. But it sure is a great comment. @JosephMarikle

Comment: It just should be there. It is a variable available for all JS included in a webpage. @user1856596

Comment: Typo: there is no `document.getElementByTagName` (you need `document.getElementsByTagName`).